# Open source, simple Adobe Acrobat plugin (C++)

Tags: open-source, pdf, c++, educational, plug-in

I am looking for an open source, simple Adobe Acrobat plugin (C++). That'd be convenient to get started to learn the plugin framework. Preference if the plugin do some text analysis (e.g., spell checking or extract all words starting with a capital letter).

Answer (score 0):

I just saw the [acrobatsdk_samplesguide.pdf](https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/acrobatsdk/pdfs/acrobatsdk_samplesguide.pdf) from the official Adobe SDK documentation, which contains some  basic C++ plug-ins given as examples.